# Avoid for loops over colum values in a pandas dataframe with a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following structur of a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Level': ["a","b", "c"], 'Kontogruppe': ["a", "a", "b"], 
                   'model': ["alpha", "beta", "alpha"], 'MSE': [0, 1 ,1],
                   'actual_value': [1,2,3], 'forecast_value': [2,2,2]})
```

For this dataframe I run severel functions, for example:

```
def metrics(df):
    df_map= pd.DataFrame({'Level': ["a"], 'Kontogruppe': ["a"],
                            'model': ["alpha"], 'MSE': [0]})
    for i in df['Level'].unique():
        for j in df['Kontogruppe'].unique():
            for k in df['model'].unique():
                df_lkm = df.loc[(df['Level'] == i) & (df['Kontogruppe'] == j) & 
                                    (df['model'] == k)]
                if df_lkm.empty:
                    out_MSE = 10000000000                   

                else:
                    out_MSE = sum(df_lkm['actual_value'])/sum(df_lkm['forecast_value'])                    

                df_map_map = pd.DataFrame({'Level': [i], 'Kontogruppe': [j], 'model': [k], 
                                        'out_MSE': [out_MSE]}) 
                df_map = pd.concat([df_map, df_map_map])
            

                
    df = pd.merge(df, df_map, how='left', on=['Level', 'Kontogruppe', 'model'])   
                    
    return df

df = metrics(df)
```

so basically I loop over the unique column values and filter the dataframe based on this.
In this case I get for every Level, Kontogruppe and model the value 'out_MSE' gets calculated over all entries of actual_values and forecast_values. And is appended as a value for every row in a new column.

For this problem is there are more efficient way to this?
Is there any pythonic way in general to avoid this for loops, my dataframe is big and this costs a lot of performance.

Comment: You code is not correctly indented and has syntax errors, please make sure it is correctly working. Also explain what it is supposed to do

Comment: `IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`, please **check** that the code is valid…

Comment: `df_map_map` is not defined

Comment: Don't use `for` loops over `df['column'].unique()` just use `df.groupby`

Comment: actual_value is definied in the dataframe or not?

Comment: My bad I missed that part of the edit

Comment: Do you really mean to loop over all combinations of Level/Kontogruppe/model? Or would you like only the **existing** combinations?

Comment: only the existing combinations

Comment: Could you provide the exact expected output that matched the given input? If you don't care about the non-existing combinations, I guess you shouldn't have multiple rows per combination like your current code it yielding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you might just want a simple [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html) with a bit of post-processing. Because you only care about the existing combinations, there is no need to loop over all of them and assign a large value.

```
(df.groupby(['Level', 'Kontogruppe', 'model'], as_index=False)
   [['actual_value', 'forecast_value']].sum()
   .eval('out_MSE = actual_value/forecast_value')
)
```

Output:

```
  Level Kontogruppe  model  actual_value  forecast_value  out_MSE
0     a           a  alpha             1               2      0.5
1     b           a   beta             2               2      1.0
2     c           b  alpha             3               2      1.5
```

Output of your code for comparison:

```
  Level Kontogruppe  model  MSE_x  actual_value  forecast_value  MSE_y  out_MSE
0     a           a  alpha      0             1               2    0.0      NaN
1     a           a  alpha      0             1               2    NaN      0.5
2     b           a   beta      1             2               2    NaN      1.0
3     c           b  alpha      1             3               2    NaN      1.5
```

Comment: what if I don't want to sum and instead using a function like `mean_quared_error` from sklearn ?

Comment: As long as you can aggregate with this function first and then compute the ratio, the logic is unchanged. Then use `groupby.agg(your_function_that_accepts_a_series)`

Comment: Be careful, many `sklearn` function need a 2D input in this case you might need to use `agg(lambda s: func(s.to_frame()))` or similar